# How to make this regex ((?:\w\s*)+) extract substrings that include dots, commas and/or line breaks?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, string, regex-group

how to make this regex grab the entire string in the middle without being cut if it detects, points`.`, commas `,`, colons `:` or semicolons`;`

The only case where the regex should not grab the text is if there is a line break between the set ends

```py
import re

input_text = "cerca de abbaab como estas?. Creo yo que bien,aunque solo haya 9 de ellas pero : no estoy muy segura ccccrrru, y luego..."

some_text = "\s*((?:\w\s*)+)\s*"  #need to fix this 

regex_pattern = r"(?:abbaab)" + some_text + r"(?:ccccrrru)"

m1 = re.search(regex_pattern, input_text, re.IGNORECASE)

if(m1):
    association = m1.group()

    print(repr(association)) #output
```

And the correct output is:

`' como estas?. Creo yo que bien,aunque solo haya 9 de ellas pero : no estoy muy segura '`

---

And how should I modify the regex to cover line breaks as well? For example for this input:

```py
input_text = """cerca de abbaab como estas?. 
Creo yo que bien,aunque solo haya 9 de ellas. 
pero : no estoy muy segura ccccrrru, y luego...
Quizas sea."""
```

And the correct output for this case is:

```
' como estas?. 
Creo yo que bien,aunque solo haya 9 de ellas. 
pero : no estoy muy segura '
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just make a character class with the additional letters you want:

```
some_text = r'\s*((?:[a-z0-9.,:.?]+\s+)+)'
```

Or simplify life and just use `.` to match any character:

```
some_text = r'\s*(.*?)'
```

If you use the latter solution, making the regex match line breaks as well is as simple as adding the `re.DOTALL` flag:

```
import re

some_text = r'\s*(.*?)'
regex_pattern = r"(?:abbaab)" + some_text + r"(?:ccccrrru)"

input_text = "cerca de abbaab como estas?. Creo yo que bien,aunque solo haya 9 de ellas pero : no estoy muy segura ccccrrru, y luego..."

m1 = re.search(regex_pattern, input_text, re.IGNORECASE)
print(m1.group(1))

input_text = """cerca de abbaab como estas?. 
Creo yo que bien,aunque solo haya 9 de ellas. 
pero : no estoy muy segura ccccrrru, y luego...
Quizas sea."""

m1 = re.search(regex_pattern, input_text, re.IGNORECASE)
print(m1)

m1 = re.search(regex_pattern, input_text, re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL)
print(m1.group(1))
```

Output:

```
como estas?. Creo yo que bien,aunque solo haya 9 de ellas pero : no estoy muy segura
None
como estas?.
Creo yo que bien,aunque solo haya 9 de ellas.
pero : no estoy muy segura
```